# How to add a column after some specific column in YUI data table?

Tags: yui, yui-datatable

I am using YUI2 datatable.
consider the following scenario.

```
var myColumnDefs = [ 
                { key:"A", label:"A", sortable:true},
                { key:"C", label:"C", sortable:true}
            ];


   // i want to add this column after A.
   myColumnDefs.push({ key:'B',label:'B'});
```

this code will generate columns A,C,B but i want it to be A,B,C. how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the columns definition before passing them to the yui datatable constructor:

myCOlumnDefs.sort(function(c1, c2){

```
return c1.key > c2.key ? 1 : -1;
```

});